# How to perform searches in a tag table while adding an entry into db?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below;

**table_a**

```
|-------+---------|
| tagid | tagname |
|-------+---------|
| 1234  | taga    |
|-------+---------|
| 2345  | tagb    |
|-------+---------|
| 3456  | tagc    |
|-------+---------|
| 4567  | tagd    |
|-------+---------|
```

**table_b**

```
|-------+--------+-----------|
| id    | entry  | tags      |
|-------+--------+-----------|
| 1111  | entry1 | taga,tagb |
|-------+--------+-----------|
| 2222  | entry2 | tagb,tagc |
|-------+--------+-----------|
| 3333  | entry3 | tagd      |
|-------+--------+-----------|
| 4444  | entry4 | tage      |
|-------+--------+-----------|
```

Whenever I add an entry to **table_b**, I want to check if tag exists in **table_a**. What I do now is putting tags of entry into an array, and check the number of rows, for each tag, like,

```
$msg = "";
$tagarray = array("taga","tagb","tagc");
foreach($tagarray as $tags){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table_a` WHERE tagname = '$tags'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows == 0){
        $msg .=  $tags.",";
    }
}
```

In this way, I can catch all tags which are not resent into `$msg` variable. But here, I need to perform separate checks for each tags. Is there any other better method to achieve the same? I want to catch all tags not present in `table_a`, while adding an entry into `table_b`.

Comment: Try as `SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE tagname NOT IN ('taga','tagb','tagc')`

Answer (score 0):

To search multiple values in a column you have the [IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) ,you could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to cast the array into the right format using comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$msg = "";
$tagarray = array("taga","tagb","tagc");
$c=0;
$tagStr='';
//create string for sql query in IN format
foreach($tagarray as $tags)
{
    if($c==0)
        $tagStr.="'$tags'";
    else
        $tagStr.=",'$tags'";
    $c++;
}
$msg=implode(",",$tagarray );
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_a` WHERE tagname IN($tagStr)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
//existed tags 
if($numrows != 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //replace them from original string
        $msg=str_replace($row["tagname"],"",$msg);
        if($msg[count($msg)]==",")
            $msg[count($msg)]='';
        if($msg[0]==",")
            $msg[0]="";
    }

}
$msg=chop($msg); //string ready for insert
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with following,

```
$msg = "";
$tagarray = array("taga","tagb","tagc");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table_a` WHERE tagname IN (".implode(',',$tagarray).")";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows == 0){
        $msg .=  implode(',',$tagarray);
    }
```

Comment: where do $tags come from?